# Making Popuo in Svg hover

Tags: javascript, css, svg

iam trying few hours to do pop up when iam over SVG drawing but nothing work.
that's what I try

```
  <text id="thingyouhoverover" x="50" y="35" font-size="14">Mouse over me!</text>
  <text id="thepopup" x="250" y="100" font-size="30" fill="black" visibility="hidden">Change me
    <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="thingyouhoverover.mouseover" end="thingyouhoverover.mouseout"/>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ha5tkne/1/#&togetherjs=n3JuckPt5R)

Comment: The code in the question works perfectly fine in Firefox. No idea what the jsfiddle is about though.

Comment: any way its not my problem.i just want to do pop up on hover svg

Comment: As I said, I ran it in Firefox and it works so whst exactly is your problem?